# Custom .NET Core Template - Solution File converts '.' to '_'

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I have created a multiple project template using template.json for .Net Core, and installed this.

When I try to create a new solution from this template using the command:

```
dotnet new tw-ms -n Tripwire.Customers
```

The solution and projects create, but in the sln file the projects are referenced as follows:

```
Project("{GUID}") = "Tripwire_Customers.Microservice", "Tripwire_Customers.Microservice\Tripwire_Customers.Microservice.csproj", "{GUID2}"
EndProject
```

So the period '.' has been converted to an underscore '_'. On disk, the projects are using the period, so when I try to open the solution it can't find the projects.

My template.json appears as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "Chelsea Farley",
  "classifications": [ ".Net Core", "Web API", "Microservice" ], 
  "name": "Tripwire Microservice",
  "identity": "TW.Template.Microservice",         
  "shortName": "tw-ms",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type":"project"
  },
  "sourceName": "Template"
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?